# Date/Time field that does not shows the time on workflow email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a form which contains a workflow which notifies an area by email when a new item has been created. 
The email output contains the date/time field from the form which is a proposed date selected by the user. 
The date/time field is set to not show the time but on the email the time appears. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your field look up, choose Short Date as shown in the image below

[image]

Here's the email I received

[image]